# How can I Sum specific columns in a dataframe based on index value provided in a different df. Return the sum and Boolean T/F

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, sum

I have two pandas dataframes. *df_lst* contains a list of column names and expected value, and *df* has a series of data.

The column names in *df_lst* may change and I use the following script to look up the column index from *df* that aligns to the column name in *df_lst* Showing this code incase it is an extra step that might not be needed.

```
ind_dict = dict((k,i) for i,k in enumerate(d.columns))
inter = set(df_lst['Col_Name']).intersection(df)
df_lst['Index'] = [ ind_dict[x] for x in inter ]
```

The input for this task would look like this:

```
import random
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

a = np.random.randint(12, size=(7, 11))
df = pd.DataFrame(a, ['foo','foo','bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'], ['a','b','f','g','h','j' ,'k', 'r', 's', 't', 'z'])

df_lst = pd.DataFrame({'Col_Name': ['Col_g', 'Col_j', 'Col_r', 'Col_s'], 
                   'Expected Value': [100, 90, 122, 111],                                      
                   'Index': [4, 6, 8, 9]})
```

How can I use the new Index values to look at that corresponding column in *df* and sum the values and return both the summed value and a 'True' if greater than or 'False' if less than for each row in *df_lst*

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame({'Col_Name': ['Col_g', 'Col_j', 'Col_r', 'Col_s'], 
                   'Expected Value': [100, 90, 122, 111],                                      
                   'Index': [4, 6, 8, 9],
                   'Sum of Col': ['sum of col_g', 'sum of col_j', 'sum of col_r', 'sum of col_s'],
                   'Bool': ['True or False', 'True or False', 'True or False', 'True or False']
                   })
```

Eventually this True/False data will be part of a while loop that checks something like "while 1 or more is false do X"

Comment: Don't describe your data in words. Instead,  provide all the info needed to understand clearly your problem and that allow us to reproduce it. This means making an example showing a  sample of `df`, `df_lst` and the expected output (explained). See here how to make a  [good pandas reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples). Help us to help you.

Comment: OK, I will update the post. Thanks for the advice :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can select the values from `df` using the values from `df_lst['Index']` and [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) we will need to subtract 1 to convert from 1 based indexing to 0 based. Then [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html) the column and [`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) back to the DataFrame. We can then compute the `Bool` column based on the new `Sum of Col` values:

```
df_out = df_lst.join(
    df.iloc[:, df_lst['Index'] - 1].sum()
        .add_prefix('Col_')
        .rename('Sum of Col'),
    on='Col_Name'
)

df_out['Bool'] = df_out['Sum of Col'] > df_out['Expected Value']
```

`df_out`:

```
  Col_Name  Expected Value  Index  Sum of Col   Bool
0    Col_g             100      4         106   True
1    Col_j              90      6          97   True
2    Col_r             122      8          95  False
3    Col_s             111      9         113   True
```

---

Steps:

Select with [`iloc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iloc.html) notice that integer indexes start at 0 so the `g` column is at index 3 not 4:

```
df.iloc[:, df_lst['Index'] - 1]

      g   j   r   s
foo   0   7  14  16
foo  23  13  12  12
bar   5  13   3  16
bar  17  13  24  16
bar  24  14  11  23
foo  17  19  24  17
foo  20  18   7  13
```

Sum Columns with [`sum`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.sum.html):

```
df.iloc[:, df_lst['Index'] - 1].sum()
Out[3]: 
g    106
j     97
r     95
s    113
dtype: int64
```

[`add_prefix`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.add_prefix.html) so columns match `Col_Name` column and [`rename`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename.html) the Series so that the new column has the correct name:

```
df.iloc[:, df_lst['Index'] - 1].sum().add_prefix('Col_').rename('Sum of Col')

Col_g    106
Col_j     97
Col_r     95
Col_s    113
Name: Sum of Col, dtype: int64
```

[`join`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) together with `df_lst`:

```
df_lst.join(
    df.iloc[:, df_lst['Index'] - 1].sum()
        .add_prefix('Col_')
        .rename('Sum of Col'),
    on='Col_Name'
)

  Col_Name  Expected Value  Index  Sum of Col
0    Col_g             100      4         106
1    Col_j              90      6          97
2    Col_r             122      8          95
3    Col_s             111      9         113
```

Do whatever comparisons are needed and add any additional columns:

```
df_out['Bool'] = df_out['Sum of Col'] > df_out['Expected Value']

  Col_Name  Expected Value  Index  Sum of Col   Bool
0    Col_g             100      4         106   True
1    Col_j              90      6          97   True
2    Col_r             122      8          95  False
3    Col_s             111      9         113   True
```

---

Reproducible Setup:

```
import pandas as pd
from numpy.random import Generator, MT19937

rng = Generator(MT19937(25))
a = rng.integers(25, size=(7, 11))
df = pd.DataFrame(a, ['foo', 'foo', 'bar', 'bar', 'bar', 'foo', 'foo'],
                  ['a', 'b', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'j', 'k', 'r', 's', 't', 'z'])

df_lst = pd.DataFrame({'Col_Name': ['Col_g', 'Col_j', 'Col_r', 'Col_s'],
                       'Expected Value': [100, 90, 122, 111],
                       'Index': [4, 6, 8, 9]})
```

Comment: Thank you for breaking down each step. That is really helpful as I learn more! Ill work in building this into my script and then move onto trying to wrap it into a while loop.